# kubuntu 17.04 , conflicting kebyoard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I have Kubuntu 17.04 (upgraded from 16.10)

In Kubuntu 17.04 `alt+shift` conflict with `alt+shift+f` (or any `alt+shift+...`)

`alt+shift+f` is a Netbeans shortcut and I had no problem in Kubuntu 16.10, but in Kubuntu 17.04 when I press `alt+shift+f` , keyboard layout changed (`alt+shift` done) and then Written 'f'

Comment: Can you just override the keyboard shortcut? Also, does this same thing happen in other input environment say in Kate or terminal?

Comment: They broke it intentionally https://bugs.launchpad.net/xorg-server/+bug/36812/comments/214 I regret I switched to 17.04 :(

Comment: See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/973007/66509) on duplicate question.