# Keyboard shortcuts fails after upgrade to 17.04 (layout switcher)

Tags: upgrade, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 17.04

I have upgraded Ubuntu MATE 16.10 to 17.04. Now I have a problems with keyboard shortcuts. So, I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch keyboard layouts. Words selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd>) worked on 16.10 and failed after upgrade. I have switched keyboard layout to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and words selection starts to work again. I found the [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910125/kubuntu-17-04-conflicting-kebyoard-shortcuts) without answer.

How can I use my favorite layout switcher combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and words selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd>) at the same time?

Comment: They broke it intentionally https://bugs.launchpad.net/xorg-server/+bug/36812/comments/214 I regret I switched to 17.04 :(

Answer (score 1):

It is known ugly bug - see [launchpad bug 1245473](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1245473).

I'm writing this from Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with MATE DE. It does not have this problem.
I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> layout switcher for English and Russian languages.

But MATE on Ubuntu 17.10 has this problem - see other [launchpad bug 1720364](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1720364).

My complete position is written [in comment 528 for bug 1218322 at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322/comments/528).